# Modifying AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY for partitioning

Tags: mysql, primary-key, partitioning, auto-increment

I need to partition a MySQL table amongst temporal data (field begin in the following table).

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `fk_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,  
  `begin` bigint(20) NOT NULL,     
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK1E57078DB20EC268` (`fk_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=10443288 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

When I try to partition like this :

```
alter table table1 partition by range (begin) (
PARTITION until_2010_07 VALUES LESS THAN (1280620800000),
PARTITION 2010_08 VALUES LESS THAN (1283299200000),
PARTITION 2010_09 VALUES LESS THAN (1285891200000),
PARTITION 2010_10 VALUES LESS THAN (1288569600000),
PARTITION 2010_11 VALUES LESS THAN (1291161600000),
PARTITION 2010_12 VALUES LESS THAN (1293840000000),
PARTITION from_2011 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

I get a MySQL error : `ERROR 1503 (HY000): A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function`

As I understand from the mysql doc, a partitioning column should belongs to the primary key.
The problem for me is that I want to change the PRIMARY_KEY to be a composite one ie `PRIMARY KEY ('id','fk_id','begin')` without changing the existing id columns (because it's a field that is used in the application to generate bookmarkable urls, so renumbering the ids is not an option)

How can I alter the PRIMARY_KEY so that I can do my partitioning ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally found a way to do it, I answer for the sake of other people who come across this question

```
//drop auto_increment capability
alter table table1 change column id id BIGINT NOT NULL;
//in one line, drop primary key and rebuild one
alter table table1 drop primary key, add primary key(id,fk_id,begin);
//re add the auto_increment capability, last value is remembered
alter table table1 change column id id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
//build the partition
alter table table1 partition by range (begin) ( 
    PARTITION until_2010_07 VALUES LESS THAN (1280620800000), 
    PARTITION 2010_08 VALUES LESS THAN (1283299200000), 
    PARTITION 2010_09 VALUES LESS THAN (1285891200000), 
    PARTITION 2010_10 VALUES LESS THAN (1288569600000), 
    PARTITION 2010_11 VALUES LESS THAN (1291161600000), 
    PARTITION 2010_12 VALUES LESS THAN (1293840000000), 
    PARTITION from_2011 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE 
);
```

Partitioning is indeed really  easy, but I advice people to think about it while creating the primary key before actually using their database in production :-)

Each step takes 3 minutes on my laptop, then i'll have to stop the service to keep consistency in my database

Comment: Why did you need to drop the auto increment? Shouldn't you be able to drop its primary key while still keeping the auto increment?

Comment: Since this answer still pops up when searching: I believe the OP dropped auto increment before changing primary key because auto increment requires an index on the column. It may be possible to avoid dropping auto increment by manually creating an additional index on id before changing primary key.